# In Python, how can I turn an oval back from the edge of the canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

def mozog():
    global x

    if x == wmax:
        x = x - 20

    can.coords(oval, x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r)

###

r = 10
x = 200
y = 100

wmax = 400
wmin = 0

#

win = Tk()
win.title("Canvas")

can = Canvas(win, width = wmax, height = 200, bg = "gray")
can.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

oval = can.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, fill= "red")

but = Button(win, text = "Move", command = mozog)
but.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
```

My task was to create an oval and move it to the right and when it reaches the edge of the canvas it should go back to the left side etc. I tried ifs but those weren't good. I can't figure out the solution, but I am sure that it is so easy.
Could you help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried simply resetting `x` to zero once it is greater than `wmax`?

Comment: once it reached wmax it has to go back from the right to the left side with 20pixels not just jumping to zero

Answer (score 0):

Right now your oval doesn't do anything.

Here's one way to make the oval move to the right, then bounce back to the left.

```
delta = 10

def mozog():
    global x, delta

    x += delta

    if x >= wmax:
        delta *= -1

    can.coords(oval, x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r)
```